# List c#, Traverse through List to collate data

Tags: c#, list

I have created a class in C#, lets say:

```
{
public string AppName {get; set;}
public int LogCount {get; set;}
}
```

And I have a List(ApplicationLogs) where I have following items:

1. AP1,1000
2. AP1/,100
3. AP1/000,50
4. AP1/010,40
5. AP2,2000
6. AP2/,200
7. AP2/010,100
8. AP2/100,50

Where AP1 is main applications, and AP1/nnn or AP1/ are sub-application. I need to traverse through the List and come up with final list where we have only main applications and log count from the main application and sub-application as well, like below:

1. AP1,1190 as (1000+100+50+40)
2. AP2,2350 as(2000+200+100+50)

A For or Foreach loop logic is way too complex and as I am just a beginner, that's all I could come up with. Could you please let me know if there is a simpler way to do it.

Thank you Friends, looking forward to this.

Comment: "A For or Foreach loop logic is way too complex" How is this complex? If you need to traverse your list, you need to - well - traverse it using some kind of loop. So can you please be more specific on what you´ve tried and where you´re stuck?

Comment: As a beginner using for and foreach is the right way to go. When you have fully understood them you can use some other techniques that might look more compact but neverless are also just loops and internally will almost likely use for/foreach also. You just don't see them.

Comment: Where is your `foreach` logic?

Comment: i agree with all comment above, for/for-each is the most simple way to achieve this... so i would suggest that if you have a for/for-each, you could then ask... how can i do this another way to achieve x while my y solution did not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A for or foreach loop IS the simplest way to achieve that, loops are one of the basics of programming. You can exchange a foreach loop with a lambda or LINQ expression which can be "simpler" if you are familiar with SQL. Such an expression can look like:

```
var c = from log in List
where log.AppName == "AP1"
select log;
```

Comment: However this also loops the collection using some old-school loop.

Comment: alright, but he doesn't care about the implementation of it ;)

Comment: How do you know that? All OP states is "loops are too complex".

Comment: As you say, "its too complex" my thought was: "looping? thats the baseline of all programming solutions... pretty nothing can be solved without it" but the OP just wants to use a loop, but spare the implementation of it an that can be achieved with lambdas or LINQ, with other problems.

Comment: Although I like your sql answer more than mine, your suggestion isn't the full solution. This obscures somewhat that the full solution is more complex.

Comment: well, if you are not willing to implement a loop yourself, you will always end up with a big mess. lambda and LINQ can be quite simple and very useful, but if you have several conditions you end up with deleting everything and implement a plain loop :) but that was not asked for ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a chain of linq methods for this. Something like this ought to do it:

```cs
ApplicationLogs
    .GroupBy(log => log.AppName.Split('/').First())
    .Select(grp => new ApplicationLog
    {
        AppName = grp.Key,
        LogCount = grp.Sum(log => log.LogCount)
    });
```

Comment: Wow, loops are too complex, but this would be fine? I doubt that will help OP much.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a perfect case for [Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries)

```
var aggregatedCounts = logs.GroupBy(l => l.AppName.Substring(0, 3), (key, sublogs) => new { Key = key, Count = sublogs.Sum(sl => sl.LogCount) });
```

You can make this better, but this is the gist of it.

Comment: Wow, loops are too complex, but this would be fine? I doubt that will help OP much.